# Spring boot 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, servlets

Hello I am struggling to figure out what is my issue. Teacher did this in eclipse. I am on Intelleji. I made a project with Java 17 and the SDK 17 too. Spring boot 3.0.0 m1

It is basic code but when I try to get it working i get error 404. Driving me nuts. If anyone sees something that I am not seeing i would be extremely grateful.

the link i try in postman is as follow: localhost:8081/restws/services/patientservice/patients

which is what the teacher did in eclipse or string tool suite.
I am in intelleji ultimate.

thank you for any help.

my structure goes as follow:

```
.
└── restws
    ├── PatientService.java
    ├── PatientServiceImpl.java
    ├── RestwsApplication.java
    └── model
        └── Patient.java
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.slinky</groupId>
<artifactId>restws</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>restws</name>
<description>restws</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

PatientService.java

```
    package com.slinky.restws;

import com.slinky.restws.model.Patient;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;

import java.util.List;

@Path("/patientservice")
public interface PatientService {
    @Path("/patients")
    @GET
    List<Patient> getPatient();
}
```

Patient.java from com.slinky.restws.model

```
  package com.slinky.restws.model;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Patient")
public class Patient {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan=true
cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages=org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs, com.slinky.restws
server.servlet.context-path=/restws
server.port=8081
```

PatientServiceImpl.java

```
package com.slinky.restws;

import com.slinky.restws.model.Patient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;

@Service
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService{
    Map<Long, Patient> patients = new HashMap<>();
    long currentId = 123;

    public PatientServiceImpl() {
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setId(currentId);
        patient.setName("John");
        patients.put(patient.getId(), patient);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Patient> getPatient() {
        Collection<Patient> results = patients.values();
        List<Patient> response = new ArrayList<>(results);
        return response;
    }
}
```

main which was created automatically

```
package com.slinky.restws;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestwsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestwsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://localhost:8081/restws/patientservice/patients ? Or change the config to server.servlet.context-path=/restws/services

Comment: thanks. I was able to solve it by using older version of java. I did not realize I was importing jarkata in spring boot, had to switch to older version to stay on javax packages.